# Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete directory

Tags: azure

Anyone know the solution for this? Using the latest version of Azure tools and every time I do a build I see these messages in the output window:

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete directory APPROOT.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete directory WEBUX.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete directory APPROOT.
```

Answer (score 2):

Angela, it is very much possible that an application has open handle to these folders and build process could not delete the folder/files so it can update with new binaries. This problem is specific to your machine, not Windows Azure.

If you could not figure out which application is using, what you could do is restart your machine so you know none of any application is using and then start Visual Studio and clean/rebuild your application and see if you still see this error. If you still see the error, I can provide some other troubleshooting info to help you further.

Comment: I had something similar, and rebooting the site and deleting before it gets started up, seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error too.  Azure SDK 1.7 added a new way to deliver 'extra' file resources upto the roles.  To fix my this error, I manually deleted the folders under the Azure project, Profile roles after exiting VS.

Answer (score 0):

As Avkash mentioned, some app is using your files... a few suggestions that worked for me:

1) Prevent antiviruses from inspecting the build folders
2) Disable Windows search service
3) Disable any auto-backup or auto-sync services that look at build folders

HTH